# QUERY and Counta

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here I am again, asking amateur questions. Hope you guys able to help out. What I want to accomplish here is to use query formula to select unique in Col A and after that to count each categories respectively. As I want to make this dynamic, I also to able to further filter based on the criteria in I2 and I3.

**Here is the link to the trix [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=137332614)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(A4:C, 
 "select A,count(A) 
  where C = '"&I3&"' 
    and B = '"&I2&"' group by A
  label count(A)''")
```

[image]

btw, those are not dates. you can check it with `ISDATE()` function